# desencriptar con libreria commons codec

Tags: apache, criptografía

en un método de crear estoy encriptando una contraseña y guardándola en una base de datos, ahora en un método validación obtengo esa cadena pero no se como desencriptarla. estoy utilizando la librería commons codec de apache. ¿como lo hago?
de esta manera la encripto

```
String clave = DigestUtils.sha1Hex(pass);
```

de esta manera optengo de la bd

```
while (rs.next()) {
                passw = (rs.getString("Pass"));

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

bueno despues de mucho investigar resulta que El sha1 no es para cifrar descifrar, sino para crear huella, es de una sola via.

se guarda el resultado del sha1, y para verificar el pass se tiene que pasar otra vez con Sha1, si es igual al almacenado en la bd, es correcto el password.